# jquery nested element loop each item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested element like this.

```
<hero id="1">
    <hero id="2">
        <hero id="3">
           <hero id="4"></hero></hero>
    </hero>
</hero>
```

I am gettings this as an jquery `element` object.

I want to get for or foreach loop this items.

```
$(element).each(function(){
    // get items with order 1, 2, 3, 4
})
```

How can I get each item?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: `$("hero").each(function() { console.log($(this).attr("id")); });`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return array of ids you can use `map()` and `get()`

```js
var ids = $('hero').andSelf().map(function() {
  return $(this).find('hero').attr('id')
}).get()

console.log(ids)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hero id="1">
  <hero id="2">
    <hero id="3">
      <hero id="4"></hero>
    </hero>
  </hero>
</hero>
```

If you want to select each element you can use `find()` and `each` loop.

```js
var ids = $('hero').andSelf().find('hero').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hero id="1">
  <hero id="2">
    <hero id="3">
      <hero id="4"></hero>
    </hero>
  </hero>
</hero>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, one recursively the other via the IDs.

If you know the IDs, you can easily do this via:

```js
// if you know ids
$('#1, #2, #3, #4').each(function (index, element) { ... });

// if you know the class/element name etc.
$('hero').each(function (index, element) { ... });
```

The other method being through recursion:

```js
function getHero($elements) {
  // do stuff with element

  if ($elements.children('hero').length) {
    getHero($elements.children('hero'));  // recursively call getHero with all immediate children
  }
}

getHero($('#1'));
```